# Dúvida - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso pegar o valor da caixa texto e colocá-lo em uma variável global. Como faço isso?

Comment: Pergunta ampla D+. Caso o valor seja pego através de uma função, basta não declarar a variável que ela se torna global.

Comment: Tentou assim? `variavel = $('#idDaCaixaDeTexto').val()`